# Integrated nuget, how to include dependant project into package

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Let's consider project **A** and project **B**. I would like to publish project **A** as a nuget package without having to publish project **B**. In the old time I would use manually **nuget ... A.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects**. Currently, when nuget is integrated with visual studio, it just interpret `.csproj` on build with some options like `authors`, `tags` etc... However it looks like there is no option to use `IncludeReferencedProjects` here. How would I use it? Is it possible to change default command that msbuild is running with and add this switch?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no official solution for having multiple projects in one nuget package, similar to IncludeReferencedProjects for "nuget pack".

But you can do:

```
1. Add 'PrivateAssets="all" to all 'ProjectReference' XmlElements.

2. Add ItemGroup to include DLL's:
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(OutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib/$(TargetFramework)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```